# One line console command to set first root password in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I need to setup GitLab and runner, create user and projects, register runner - automatically via user data in terraform. It could be possible via API with bash or python scripts.

To use API we need ACCESS_TOKEN - with this script  https://gist.github.com/vitalyisaev2/215f890e75252cd36794221c2debf365 it is possible to create ACCESS_TOKEN for root user.

But first I need to have a valid root user password. This is a big problem for me I can not solve and ask You guys to help me.

On first login GitLab asks to set/change password. 
[First login to GitLab UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHtJD.png)

I want to set this password via script, non interactively. 
It is possible set password this way:

```
gitlab-rails console 
irb(main):001:0> user = User.where(id: 1).first
irb(main):001:0> user.password = user.password_confirmation ='IrF8WCsZJlMP'
irb(main):001:0> user.save!
irb(main):001:0> exit
```

But, it is not suitable for me, because I can not input commands interactively. I need one line command to set password, or set it while installing gitlab-ce.

This way doesn't work too, it doesn't set password, only EXTERNAL_URL :

```
sudo GITLAB_ROOT_EMAIL="some@email.com" GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD="nTjYfcKxcW" EXTERNAL_URL="http://example.com" yum install gitlab-ce
```

Please help to set first gitlab root password non interactively, without visiting browser, via console with one line command or while gitlab-ce installation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb i found "gitlab_rails['initial_root_password"

So, I solved my problem this way

```
sed -i"" "s#\# gitlab_rails\['initial_root_password.*#gitlab_rails\['initial_root_password'\] = \""${GITLAB_INITIAL_ROOT_PASSWD}"\"#g" /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

Need to set "root_initial_password" before first "gitlab-ctl reconfigure" command

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset[root]"
```

can reset the root password.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gitlab-rake "gitlab:password:reset"
```

This is the most clear command to give username, password and password confirmation.